# How do I make the headphone jack on my desktop mac work?

Tags: sound, mac

I can plug headphones into the headphone jack, run `alsamixer` and see that I've just got `00` instead of `M` meaning the headphone jack is not muted.  But no sound comes out.

Comment: Is there a red light coming out of the headphone jack? I remember having an issue with a Mac Mini where the light would stay red (meaning optical output) and you had to change it.

Comment: Does sound come out of the computer instead, or is there no sound at all?

Comment: @reverendj1 Yes, there is a red light coming out of the jack, now that you mention it.  How would I go about changing this?

Comment: @Steve Kroon The sound continues to come out of the computer as if I hadn't done anything.

Comment: Do the headphones show as an output if you click on the speaker at the top right of the screen and select "Sound Settings"? Can you change to the headphones using that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'options snd-hda-intel model=mbp55' >> /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf"
```

from the [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Macmini4-1/Maverick)

Comment: Before blindly doing that, I looked at the end of /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf and am reminded that [I had to do something like this before to get sound working at all](http://pastebin.com/tcV8FKcA)

To follow your answer, should I comment out the other `snd-hda-intel` line?

Comment: Yes, I would comment out the previous one and add this new one. Also, what is the exact model of Mac you are using?

Comment: @JohnBaber  Did this command end up working?  Thanks